# How can I split a concatenated xml file and name the extracted files using strings

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed, text-processing

How do I split a large concatenated xml files into individual xml files with the files named using strings?

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1001-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1002-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1008-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

I want to read the strings `file="xxxx-yyyyyyyy.XML"` and create output files named as xxxx.XML

output xml files:

1001.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1001-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

1002.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1002-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

1008.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1008-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

My preference is to use bash shell tools such as cat, awk, sed and or xml tools such as xmllint or similar, and log stdout and stderr to a logfile.

Appreciate approaches and testable solutions

Comment: Does each doc have an ending `</type-of-doc>`, or is it invalid xml?

Comment: It's not valid if <type-of-doc> is never closed.

Comment: `My preference is to use bash shell tools such as cat, awk, sed and or xml tools such as xmllint or similar, and log stdout and stderr to a logfile` please do try any of these approaches and add the code here if you get stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following ***gawk*** approach (if your input is constructed as in the question, line by line):

```
awk '/<?xml version/{ getline dt; getline typedoc; 
     if (match(typedoc,/file="([0-9]+)-[^"]+.XML"/,a)) { 
         fn=a[1]".xml"; print $0 ORS dt ORS typedoc > fn; next; 
     }}{ print > fn }
' input.xml 2> err.log
```

Results:

```
cat 1001.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1001-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

---

```
cat 1002.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1002-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

---

```
cat 1008.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE type-of-doc SYSTEM "file.dtd" [ ]>
<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="1008-20170101.XML" date="20170101">
</type-of-doc>
```

---

- `/<?xml version/` - on encountering line `/<?xml version/` with `xml` declaration
- `getline dt;` - capture next line with `<!DOCTYPE`
- `getline typedoc;` - capture next line with starting `type-of-doc` tag
- `if (match(typedoc,/file="([0-9]+)-[^"]+.XML"/,a))` - match `file` attribute value
- the 1st captured group `([0-9]+)` will be assigned to the 1st array element `a[1]`

Comment: Thanks again. I would like to extend `if (match(typedoc,/file="([0-9]+)-[^"]+.XML"/,a))` to deal with alpha numeric strings. I have this new use case `<type-of-doc lang="EN" dtd-version="v1" file="aa1001b1-20170101.XML" date="20170101">` and want to write a file named `aa1001b1.XML` Have tested with and without the letters, looks like a problem with the array and having difficulty with the quotations, please can you suggest a revision?

Comment: @Gabe, yes, for such entry as `file="aa1001b1-20170101.XML"` use this approach `match(typedoc,/file="([^-]+)-[^"]+.XML"/,a)`

Comment: Perfect that worked a treat. Still working on the quotations and other syntax for pattern matching, gnu.org gawk manual is looking like a good starting place, but this has moved me along nicely. thanks again, have a much better sense of it now.